# Pip install error exit status 1 with Clearbit API

Tags: python, api, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to pip install clearbit per the following guidance:
[Link 1](https://pypi.org/project/clearbit/)
[Link 2](https://clearbit.com/docs?python#api-reference)

I am on Python 3.9.7 and pip version 21.3. I have also updated my setuptools per other stackoverflow answers.

The command I am running on my Mac Terminal is:

```
pip install clearbit
```

But I am met with a series of errors. An example error block states:

```
  Using cached clearbit-0.0.2.tar.gz (2.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_e710a979acd3433290a538760255e4c4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_e710a979acd3433290a538760255e4c4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-jnpe31nd
       cwd: /private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_e710a979acd3433290a538760255e4c4/
  Complete output (1 lines):
  error in clearbit setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/44/d8de83ca49c310895481e2f9d4657476c323a60b3186be7afeb584814263/clearbit-0.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=b39180db8e6ac159febe54fb0e0e84c8f0c8facf832c551c1175c758c255326b (from https://pypi.org/simple/clearbit/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

  Using cached clearbit-0.0.1.tar.gz (2.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_4716e56973294efd87482725d29438ec/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_4716e56973294efd87482725d29438ec/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-3_q7g_32
       cwd: /private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_4716e56973294efd87482725d29438ec/
  Complete output (5 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/nv/d5h78rrs0t9625k940k5f4ww0000gn/T/pip-install-plp1xoqf/clearbit_4716e56973294efd87482725d29438ec/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
      with open('README.md') as f:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/50/76018c4fd50de45bd927010ae85c7c0e2f8f385f3e90e1ca6aedc5a2ded6/clearbit-0.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=247b48b17c9052aac5551bd6fa1da617f50a8ba883ab78827df53228ead0da57 (from https://pypi.org/simple/clearbit/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement clearbit (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.4, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for clearbit
```

I can't find any guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue. I wondered if anyone has any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? I'm quite new to Python and CLI so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the package classifiers (see it [here](https://pypi.org/project/clearbit/)), it seems like `clearbit` cannot be installed on Python 3.9, because it is not on the classifiers. You have to ask the maintainers to release a Python 3.9 compatible release.

Another issue (that you should note) is that `clearbit` is using the setuptools `use_2to3` command (which is now unsupported).

Anyway, you should ask the project developers for help, or just downgrade your Python version to a compatible one (however, this is not so efficient).

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate your help!